# asynchronous mvc .net: how to return a view from async method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I'm starting to learn MVC.net and following [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx).

In there, it is explained that an async controller will implement two methods, say the action is called News, then we will have a method called NewsAsync, which **will return void**, and a NewsCompleted, which **will return a view**, and that will be invoked once the outstanding operation returns.

My concern is that, i really don't see any point to an asynchronous operation that cannot return a view after the operation started. If the user will be unable to see any feedback whatsoever from the service until the asynchronous callback returns, then why bother with an asynchronous controller in the first place?

Is there any way to return an intermediate view after the async operation starts? Am i needlessly concerned about this apparent limitation? is there something i'm missing from the MVC.net?

Comment: My article you link above is ancient, please see http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Answer (score 3):

The point of the asynchronous controller is to promote thread re-use so that if you have a particularly long running request that blocks on resources, you aren't going to be tying up the request queue. It has nothing to do with returning back information to the requesting party. To their end, they see no difference between an async controller and a normal controller.

It's not like it makes it more ajax friendly or whatever; a good example would be if you had a request start to render an image; traditionally, that request thread is going to be consumed while the CPU renders the image. With the asynchronous pattern, you can still be rendering the image, but that thread could be freed to service another web request until the render is complete, allowing greater throughput for your server.

Comment: Actually the image rendering is not a great example, there's no use in having a different thread render the image as it's still CPU intensive. A better example would be making an I/O request e.g. contacting an external Web Service or something. In that case, the request thread is blocked waiting for a response, which is a waste. It could process other requests in the interim.

Comment: Sure, that works too. The basic idea being you want threads constantly working on the request queue instead of being blocked on another resource.

Comment: No, the two are quite different actually. If a piece of work in CPU intensive, just offloading it to another thread accomplishes nothing. The other thread still has to do all the work. In fact, you'll actually LOSE performance because of context switching. For an I/O operation though, the thread waiting for the network card to finish, will be BLOCKED, and will be doing nothing. Big waste. Read up on the difference between CPU bound and I/O bound.

Comment: this answer, which has a ring of truth to it, actually confirms the worst of my concerns; This sound like a niche optimization, and it makes the Async in controller something relevant for backend performance, and completely unrelated to the presentation technology. I thought MVC was a presentation technology, but this naming decision seems to suggest otherwise

Comment: @lurscher I'm not sure why you think this is a "niche optimization". Node.js is practically predicated around this one idea, everything is asynchronous (though not for threading purposes per se). It's very easy to do, and any time you need to access an external resource, you might as well just do it and your app will scale significantly. Also, why is MVC just a "presentation" technology? It's an entire web stack, isn't it? What does M (model) have to do with presentation?

Comment: For that matter, what does C have to do with presentation either? That's the routing layer. Also, @BFree is 100% spot on.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy is to set up polling on the client. Once the result has been generated the user will be notified.